# LoadError: cannot load such file -- etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am seeing this error, after upgrading to ruby 2.7.2 using ruby-build and rbenv on Mac OS BigSur.

Rails 6.0.3.5

```
≻ bundle exec rspec spec/acceptance/roles_spec.rb    
An error occurred while loading ./spec/acceptance/roles_spec.rb. - Did you mean?
                    rspec ./spec/acceptance/users_spec.rb


Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- etc
# ./config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:7:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/acceptance_helper.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/acceptance_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/acceptance/roles_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/acceptance/roles_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

Application.rb:5 - `require "rails"`

I have tried to create a completely new Rails project with same rails and ruby version, which didn't have the same problem running rake rspec.

Comment: Can you share what's here: `./spec/rails_helper.rb:7:in `require'` ?

Comment: Yes, Rails_helper.rb:7 `require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)`

Comment: Weird, maybe this `etc` exception is only confusing. What about this part `An error occurred while loading ./spec/acceptance/roles_spec.rb. - Did you mean?
                    rspec ./spec/acceptance/users_spec.rb` are you 100% positive that `./spec/acceptance/roles_spec.rb` exists?

Comment: This error stopped appearing when I downgraded to 2.7.1. I think 2.7.2 is broken on Big Sur.

Comment: Did anybody found a solution to this instead of downgrading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue got solved after doing the following:

- Delete bootsnap cache:

  rm -rf tmp/cache/bootsnap*

This might have solved the issue, but I did also:

- Use ruby 2.7.3
- `bundle update bootsnap simplecov`
  Installing bootsnap 1.7.5 (was 1.7.2)